# Eclipse - "This project is not a CDT project"

Tags: c, eclipse, project

I have existing C-Code and an existing Makefile, which I want to wrap into an Eclipse C-Project (Using Eclipse 3.4 Ganymede). The Code is organized like this:

Main Directory: `/Project/Software`

Source and Headerfiles: `../Project/Software/CodeDir1  ../Project/Software/CodeDir2` etc..

So far I have been doing these steps:

1. Set Eclipse worksapce to /Project/
2. Create new C-Project with the name `Software` --> Now Eclipse integrates all Source files etc. into the Project
3. Go to Properties -> C/C++ Build and set to "Custom Build options"

First time I do this, everything works fine. I get the output into my console and everything is cool. But then the "Build Icon" (The little hammer) is greyed out and I cant click it anymore. If I now go to the Project Properties -> C/C++ Build it just says "This project is not a CDT Project" and also I get an Error with a "java.lang.NullPointerException".

How can I get a working project?

**edit:**

To avoid a simple bug I tried the same with the new Version of Eclipse (Kepler). I get the same Error ("No CDT Project") but without the Null Pointer exception.

But I could narrow down the problem a bit: The **first** time I start the make process it always works. If the build process fails, I can still go to my Build Properties. As soon as I get one **complete and error free** build run, this issue occurs. Regarding this, it only happens when my make call is done from Eclipse. If I call it from the command line, I can still make one run out from eclipse.

Comment: I know it sounds stupid buy has your makefile got a blank line at the end - it sounds like the build is stalling at the end.  The other question is are you using `make -f makefile` or `make -f makefile.mk` or are you calling a build script or batch file 'makefile' as __this is not a makefile__ in the meaning of building of code.

Comment: I'm using `gmake BUILD --file=...` etc and some more Parameters. And actually the problem is relating to the makefile / the make-process itself. It somehow always deletes my cproject file (which causes the error) - I'm just looking a bit more into it before I update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the problem is not located in Eclipse, it's in the makefile.

The directory structure of the whole Project is the following:

```
Project_Dir\Documentation\
Project_Dir\Output\
Project_Dir\Software\
Project_Dir\Tools\
```

The Source files are all located in the `\Software\` directory. So I chose `Project_Dir\Software\` as the project folder, which meant that the `.project` and `.cproject` files are located there.

The makefile itself temporarily writes the outputfiles in the `\Software\` folder as well. In the end it copies all files from the `Software` dir to `Output`  (practically a `move *.* Project_Dir\Output\` command)

This command was also moving the Eclipse project-files, thus making it hard for eclipse to find them and open the project properties.

**Two solutions:**

1. Change the project directory in eclipse to `\Project_Dir\` since it's all project related stuff anyway
2. Add two lines to the makefile: Before the move command: `attrib +r +s *.project` and `attrib -r -s *.project` after the move command. (Same for `.cproject`). This prevents the makefile from moving the files

Answer (score 32):

If you are importing an existing CDT project and see “This project is not a CDT project”, it could be that the project was created on an older version of Eclipse, and you need to:

- Select the project in the `Project Explorer` tab,
- Click File->New->Convert to a C/C++ project

This will add a new `.cproject` file, and you are then ready to go.

Answer (score 3):

When creating your new project you need to create it as a `makefile` project - it will then use make to build the project but setting build properties up needs to be via your makefile and the make invocation.

This [link](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/getting_started/cdt_w_newproj.htm) tells you how to create a makefile project:

> To create a project:
>
> Select File > New > Project.
>
> When you create a new project, you are required to specify the project
>   type. This project type will determine the toolchain, data, and tabs
>   that the CDT uses/displays.
>
> Select the type of project to create. For this tutorial, expand the
>   C/C++ folder and select C++ Project.  The C++ Project wizard opens.
>   Click here to see an illustration.
>
> By default, the CDT filters the Toolchain and Project types that
>   currently display in those lists are based on the language support for
>   the C++ Project wizard you selected for this tutorial.
>
> In the Project name field, type HelloWorld. Leave the Use Default
>   Location option selected.
>
> Next, you want to select the type of project to create. In the New CDT
>   Project Wizard, you can choose from the following project types:
>   Executable - Provides an executable application. This project type
>   folder contains three templates. Hello World C++ Example provides a
>   simple C++ Hello World application with main(). Hello World ANSI C
>   Example provides a simple C Hello World application with main(). Empty
>   Project provides a single source project folder that contains no
>   files. After you select this template, the result is a project with
>   only the meta-data files required for the project type. You are
>   expected to provide source files for the project's target. The
>   makefile for the Executable project type is automatically created by
>   the CDT.
>
> 1. Shared Library - An executable module that is compiled and linked separately. When you create a project that uses a shared library
>      (libxx.so), you define your shared library's project as a Project
>      Reference for your application. For this project type, the CDT
>      combines object files together and joins them so they're relocatable
>      and can be shared by many processes. Shared libraries are named using
>      the format libxx.so.version, where version is a number with a default
>      of 1. The libxx.so file usually is a symbolic link to the latest
>      version. The makefile for this project type is automatically created
>      by the CDT.
> 2. Static Library - A collection of object files that you can link into another application (libxx.a). The CDT combines object files
>      (i.e. *.o) into an archive (*.a) that is directly linked into an
>      executable. The makefile for this project type is automatically
>      created by the CDT.
> 3. Makefile Project - Creates an empty project without the meta-data files. This selection is useful for importing and modifying existing
>      makefile-based projects; a new makefile is not created for this
>      project type.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, if I select "New Project" there is no option giving me the opportunity to create a "Makefile-Project" - The only option I have was "Convert to a C/C++ Makefile Project" - I tried this and selected my old Project. Now I can select the Build Properties but it still shows up the Null Pointer exception.  Do I need a plugin or should I use another version of Eclipse?

Comment: @Toby I have added a link to instructions and a copy of the first part of them.

Comment: Nevermind, of course I can Create a Makefile Project (I unwittingly did that already). The problem is that I have no Toolchain chosen at all, but imo that shouldn't be a problem at all, since the Makefile is linking to the necessary Tools.

Comment: No you __do__ need to point to the tool chain so as to know a) which make to use, b) some details of how to parse errors & c) how to run the debugger.

Comment: Well, since I followed the instructions quite strictly, I think the only reason for my problem left is the fact I can't define a toolchain. When it comes to the point in the Project wizard where I can pick a Project Type and a Toolchain, I can only select "-- Other Toolchain --" since I have no toolchain "installed" under windows. In my makefile I'm just calling the GCC 3.4.4 I have in myp project folder. Could this be the problem?

Comment: It could be!  I would think that it would be well worth installing the mingw tool chain if you are on windows you get a lot for your money.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help. I installed MinGW and then the GCC Compiler. Then I created a new Makefile Project and chose the MinGW GCC as Toolchain. In my project I have chosen the custom Makefile but still, I get the same error...

Comment: Apparently its not related to the Toolchain (I guess...), since the error always comes after the first **error-free** build run (see my edit in the main post)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this by installing/updating corresponding CDT plugins like 'Visual C++ support'.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me when I had included **.cproject** file in my **.gitignore** and then cloned to a new PC.